# Linux - Need to limit a 16 core system to 4 to test performance running multiple programs

Tags: linux, performance, operating-system, performance-testing, cpu-usage

I have a couple of programs that will be put on a system with limited core's. 
I want to test performance of these programs on my current system that is a lot more powerful than the one it will be on.

Is the only way to fully limit the proper resource is through a Virtual Machine on my system, or can I just restrict my system to meet the same core limit as the other system my programs will run on?

Comment: Do you actually have 16 cores or just 8 cores + hyperthreading?

Comment: You will most likely not want to use a virtual machine to simulate the performance of another machine.

Comment: Another idea -- if the application is parallelized via OpenMP you might set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS=X` prior to starting the application. `X` is the number of OpenMP threads allowed to run (e.g. `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4` to allow 4 threads). Additionally, you might control the distribution of threads on cores via the env. var. `KMP_AFFINITY` (if compiled with Intel compilers). Other compiled suites should have corresponding env. vars. to set. Please let me know, if the application is OpenMP-parallelized and I will post another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`taskset` might help you.

Start your application `your_command` as follows:

```
taskset -ac 0-3 your_command
# -c 0-3: your_command might run on cores 0 to 3
#  a    : all of the 4 cores may be used
```

If the application is already running:

```
taskset -acp 0-3 PID
# PID = process ID
```

See [this answer to 'Limit process to one cpu core' at Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23109/182655) for further details .